# ios uiimagePickerController field of view

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using uiimagePickerController to take pictures and I need to process the images taken with certain data. One of them is the field of view, how am I supposed to get this value? Can uiimagePickerController return this value for me? Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the `UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata` data?